# Codeigniter: Url protection

Tags: codeigniter, url, htmlpurifier

I use mode_rewrite with codeiniter to have url's such as:

```
 /controller/param1/param2
```

Most of the times param1 and param2 will be IDs from the database (in other words numbers) and nothing else.

The question is, what can and what should I do to protect it against potential hacker attacks? Should I use html purifier for that, or is there a better way, or is there even a need to do something?

I am really new at security and protection, and I just heard about html purifier and I would rather not used it everywhere like beginners probably tend to.

Should I just preg_match()?

If preg_match() is the soluton, which expresiion accepts only numeric value (ID value)?

Comment: Are you primarily worried about XSS or SQL injection? Because the answers are different for the two attack vectors.

Comment: Both... I think. I mean the IDs are later used to access data via the db query, and before that something can probably be abused xss vise... i need to limit it so that it only accepts numeric stuff, so I thought that a preg_match() might help.

Comment: Actually I think sql injection is prevented by codeigniter's active record class.

Comment: You could just set this in the routes.php. Something like `/controller/(:num)/(:num)` would limit the params to only numeric inputs. Params with non numeric characters would redirect to a 404 by default I think.

Answer (score 2):

In your config file you can find

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+';
```

you don't need to use preg match as it's already done in Codeigniter through this  on other hand i would recommend to have validation the only the right person can access this links 
for example if there's item ID not shown to read only user or such, you can handle this by routing or redirecting after certain checks in controller

however I m not very good in security, but that what i know so far

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a codeignitor specific question but general how to scrub user input then a simple solution will be to escape & quote the value before submitting the SQL.

Something like this would work (warning: untested PHP code):

```
function escapeAndQuoteValue($value, $forceQuote = false) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
        $escapedString = 'NULL';
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $escapedString = $value ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    } elseif (isDigits($value) && $value[0] != '0') {
        $escapedString = $value; //return ints verbatim -- unless it has a leading zero
    } else {
        $escapedString = pg_escape_string($value);
    }

    $quoteString = 
        $forceQuote     ||
        is_null($value) || 
        is_bool($value) || 
         (isDigits($value) && $value[0] != '0');

    return $quoteString ? "'$escapedString'" : $escapedString;
```

}